# Jquery Animation loading content formatting

Tags: jquery, formatting

When my text loads within the animated box the text moves to the wrong place and i cannot workout where the error is within the css or jquery. How do i get it to stay in the original position thanks

Comment: Don't add email or personal home pages / contact information to your questions. Add them to your profile instead (if you want).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding `padding-top:1px;` to #story.